# SonarQube: Getting an error "Remove this redundant undefined" while passing "undefined" as a function parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sonarqube

I am passing "undefined" as a parameter multiple times for a single function call.
But in SonarQube report, I am getting an error "Remove this redundant undefined".

[image]

Note: The function having some default parameters, so I am passing "undefined" for those paramters.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript when you don't give to function a declared parameter, it's by default undefined so for your case no needed set undefined explicitly.

You can avoid SonarQube warnings like this

```
const responste = await getDocumentsByQuery(query, esIndex);
```

*And I am curious about why do you need set so many 'undefined's, can you show your whole code?*

Comment: Actually this function has some default values which I am overriding with "undefined".

Comment: As you can see Typescript already gave you correct way to override them.
For example for overriding size property you can set default size 10000. collapse, defaultOperator are optional and remaining props you can override by Typescript example. Does it make sense?

When you see in TS "?:someProperty" it means that it can be undefined .

Comment: I think what you are saying is correct, we can call the function without passing undefined which will take default arguments.